# Multiple condition formatting SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

SSRS 2008, I am trying to format the colours of the cells according to the following but the resulting format is not producing the correct colour for the fields, can anyone help?

desired output:

Admitted < 90% red > 90% green
Non-Admitted < 95% red > 95% green

```
=IIf (SUM(IIF(Fields!WEEKS_BANDING.Value = "< value" and fields!Flag.Value = "Non-Admitted",1,0)) / count (Fields!id.Value) < .95 , "Red" ,


IIf (SUM(IIF(Fields!WEEKS_BANDING.Value = "< value" and fields!Flag.Value = "Non-Admitted" ,1,0)) / count (Fields!id.Value) >= .95 , "LimeGreen" , 


IIf (SUM(IIF(Fields!WEEKS_BANDING.Value = "< value" and fields!Flag.Value = "Admitted" ,1,0)) / count (Fields!id.Value) < .90 , "Red" ,


IIf (SUM(IIF(Fields!WEEKS_BANDING.Value = "< value" and fields!Flag.Value = "Admitted" ,1,0)) / count (Fields!.Value) >= .90 , "LimeGreen" , "Transparent"))))
```

Comment: I would suggest don't make it complex.. add two calculated field with Admitted & Non-Admitted (use same expression) and then write expression color coding ..  OR try to display values of expression used SUM(IIF(Fields!WEEKS_BANDING.Value = "< value" and fields!Flag.Value = "Admitted" ,1,0) & for Non-Admitted that way you can troubleshoot

Comment: Hi, Naveen the percentages are calculating correctly, I am having trouble getting the fields coloured correctly, is it a problem with precedence somewhere?

Comment: if you are able to display correct value in columns then you can use these two column value for coloring as well.. give any name to text box like Admitted & use that as ReportItems!Admitted.value < 90 or ReportItems!Non-Admitted.value < 95

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found success by adapting the code to the below, and this has now resolved the colouring issue, many thanks for help received.

```
=IIf (fields!Flag.Value = "Non-Admitted" and (SUM(IIF(Fields!WEEKS_BANDING.Value = "< value" ,1,0)) / count (Fields!id.Value) < .95) , "Red" ,


IIf (fields!Flag.Value = "Non-Admitted" and (SUM(IIF(Fields!WEEKS_BANDING.Value = "< value" ,1,0)) / count (Fields!id.Value) >= .95) , "LimeGreen" , 


IIf (fields!Flag.Value = "Admitted" and (SUM(IIF(Fields!WEEKS_BANDING.Value = "< value" ,1,0)) / count (Fields!id.Value) < .90) , "Red" ,


IIf (fields!Flag.Value = "Admitted" and (SUM(IIF(Fields!WEEKS_BANDING.Value = "< value" ,1,0)) / count (Fields!id.Value) >= .90) , "LimeGreen" , "Transparent"))))
```